# wpf slow effect and low speed animation?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Let me explain about my problem:

I have a wpf form with few controls. some of these control over-writing template. for example a textblock with an effect will be trigger on Mouse-Enter event and change color of foreground to something else.  
But after running program when mouse enter on textBloc, it takes a few Milli-seconds until  Mouse-enter event triggers. also all control or better say all control which use mouse-events have this problem.

#### How solve this problem???

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is the event not occuring fast enough? Do you want your event trigger delayed?

Comment: yeah. I do not get the problem. You have a mouse enter event trigger and wonder it gets fires? THat is what it is for.

Comment: event occurring after Milli-seconds. and I don't wanna this delay  
also I think my Question is too clear enough!!

Comment: Your question is absolutely not clear. You ask how to solve "this problem", but you do not describe a problem. You only describe the typical behavior. If you wanted to emphasize the delay, you should change your sentence like this: "when mouse enter on textBloc, **it takes** a few Milli-seconds **until** Mouse-enter event triggers". Besides that, it is absolutely normal that it takes some milliseconds until a change occurs. However, if it is a large delay (>100ms), then you should provide some (XAML) code, so that we can see if something is wrong.

Comment: I know occurring event is take a few Milli-second but this delay is more than normal delay. so you think I'm speaking about normal delay. no I speak about delay which is abnormal.


ps(for gehho): you must pardon me.(for bad grammer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem depends on two things:
1) system configuration (CPU, RAM , VGA) also depends on power of these parts
2) Windows Version (XP,Seven) seven Much faster than Xp, xp too slow

Tip:
also you must know using wpf in windows xp two thing make this problem:
1) using effects(or bitmap-effect) on window
2) using allow transparency with none-border style for window

these effect make your window slow to occure any events and trigger!
otherwise if You not use these effect, you have a good wpf app with good speed in triggering events(also on Minimal systerm ).

Good Luck

Comment: Great answer.  I'd also like to point out that I've resolved some slow down issues by decreasing the hardware acceleration from my graphics card to the state that reads "Disable all DirectDraw and Direct3D accelerations...".  Seemed to work great for me.